# Container ReactJS : how to set state on sub components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a little problem with ReactJS. I am trying to make an MVP system (Model / View / Presenter). Just for information, this should not affect the rest, but I also use Typescript.

For this, I created simple components based on material-ui. Then my view is a React.Component, whose render function uses my lower level components and whose properties come from the statue of my view. Basically my view is a kind of component container.
My present is an object that stores a reference on my view, to be able to update its status.

Unfortunately, when I want to update the status of my view, from my presentation, in order to update the statuses of all the components used in the render, I have a message telling me that my component does not is not mounted:

> Can't call set State on a component that is not yet mounted

Indeed, it would seem that the componentDidMount function of my view is not called.

In order to display my view, from my presenter, I did the following function:

```
display (): void {
ReactDOM.render (this.view.render (), document.getElementById ('root'));
}
```

In my view, I was forced to use the refs on the components used in my render, in order to change the status on my subcomponent and not my main component (the view).

Question: is it possible to make a React component, which calls on other components (basically making a container) and when we update the status of this container, the subcomponents are updated without using the notion of ref?

If I haven't been explicit enough, I will try to provide you with a piece of code to illustrate my system.

thank you so much

EDIT : You can see my example code in this Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/q4jdeh18/. I'm sorry, but on my visual studio code editor, this code works but not on Fiddle. When I test with my editor, I have the message after clicking on the button. The label on checkbox and button does not update :

> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted.
>   This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application.
>   Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};`
>   class property with the desired state in the TestView component.

Comment: Why can’t this be resolved by passing props?

Comment: Passing properties to what function? I will try to provide sample code.

Comment: To the sub-components, like normal React. It’s not at all clear what your app structure is.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have an example link, if you want to see my code for example. In this example, i don't use ref